# How to tell VS2010's IntelliSense to ignore .glsl files

Tags: file, visual-studio-2010, glsl, intellisense

I have a C++ VS2010 solution that also has .glsl shader files (I use Visual Studio and the NShader syntax highlighter to edit them).
However, in my VS2010's "Error List" window are permanently listed up 100 errors related to these .glsl files (the most frequent error being "IntelliSense: cannot open source file xxx.glsl" - due to an #include in my .glsl file.

How can I tell IntelliSense to ignore files with this extension (since it cannot process them) ?